# Altitude lines dont appear to be perpendicular to triangle sides in botched orthocenter calculation attempt

Tags: triangles, orthogonality

I am trying to calculate the orthocenter of this triangle with vertices  `v1 = (42.9269, -307.8938), v2 = (-3816.060, 5723.502), v3 = (1766.106, 1973.672)`. My math seems to be correct, but the altitudes of the triangle do not appear to be perpendicular to the sides of the triangle.

The algorithm:

1. Find the slope $(dv_1v_2)$ for line between vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$
2. Find the slope $(dv_1v_3)$ for line between vertices $v_1$ and $v_3$
3. Calculates the negative reciprocal of both  $dv_1v_2$ and $dv_1v_3$ as these should be the slopes of the triangle altitudes $(m_{alt})$
4. Calculate $y$-Intercepts of both triangle altitudes from vertice 2 and 3: $I_{alt2}, I_{alt3}$
5. Find the intersection of these altitudes

Given the equations for the altitude lines:
$$
y = m_{alt2}\cdot x + I_{alt2} \\
y = m_{alt3}\cdot x + I_{alt3}
$$
Where $I_{alt}$ is the intercept of the altitude line given by:
$$
I_{alt3} = v_{3y} - m_{alt3} \cdot v_{3x}\\
I_{alt2} = v_{2y} - m_{alt2} \cdot v_{2x}
$$

And $m_{alt}$ is the slope of the altitude line
. Then the equation for the intersection of these two altitude lines is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    - m_{alt3} & 1  \\
    - m_{alt2} & 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{alt3} \\ I_{alt2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I wrote a code to compute it in `R`:

```
v1 <- c(42.9269, -307.8938) 
v2 <- c(-3816.060, 5723.502)
v3 <- (1766.106, 1973.672)
dv1v2 <- (v2[2] - v1[2]) / (v2[1] - v1[1])
dv1v3 <- (v3[2] - v1[2]) / (v3[1] - v1[1])
dv3B <- -1 / dv1v2
dv2A <- -1 / dv1v3

interceptV3B <- v3[2] - dv3B * v3[1]
interceptV2A <- v2[2] - dv2A * v2[1]
A <- matrix(c(-dv3B, 1, -dv2A, 1), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2)
B <- matrix(c(interceptV3B, interceptV2A), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2)
orthocenter <- solve(A) %*% B
```

For the given points, my results for the orthocenter are `(1431.956 1759.878)`. An online calculator verified the results.

Here is an image I plotted, followed by an image from an online calculator that matches.

My results (yellow is orthocenter):

[image]

Online calculator results match mine (red is orthocenter):

[image]

None of these altitudes look perpendicular to me!

This is what I expect an altitude to look like, every altitude is 90 degrees in this image:
[image]

I verified that the altitude and side between vertices is perpendicular with the formula: $angle = atan(abs((slope1-slope2)/(1+slope1*slope2)))$. This shows that the angle is $\frac{pi}{2}$, yet none of the altitudes look 90 degrees, so I don't believe it.

Why don't these altitude lines look 90 degrees to their opposite sides? Looking at the image, I would think the orthocenter would be closer to $x = 0$

Orthocenter calculator for reference: https://www.mathportal.org/calculators/analytic-geometry/triangle-calculator.php

Comment: Your triangle seems to be right angled  triangle  or even obtuse at vertex on the bottom.

Comment: Right, if it was a right angled triangle the orthocenter would be the vertice of the right angle. If obtuse, orthocenter lies outside of triangle. So why is the orthocenter calculated by me and online calculator saying otherwise?

Comment: The orthocenter calculation is correct. Your plot of the triangle is close but not accurate.

Comment: The plot does not look square; that is, the horizontal scale does not look the same as the vertical. Using the data given, I get [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryh4N.png) when plotted on a square grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct drawing:[image]

Correct drawing, angle at $v_3$ is about $86^o$